# has_many should have at least two entries and one of them should be true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, has-many

I've the following situation

User can create a question which

1. has at least 2 answers in option
2. one of it has to be marked as correct  (Answer has boolean field as 'is_correct')

For this first part I'm trying the following code in the model

The "Question" model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  validate :at_least_two_answers

  private
    def at_least_two_answers
      if answers.size < 2
        errors[:base] << "Need at least 2 answers"
      end
    end
end
```

The "Answer" model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

But I'm not able to figure out how to write validation for the second part. I'll highly appreciate any help on how can I write validation for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help. The count thing didn't work as I'm getting the `answers.count` as 0. (Must be because the record for answer is not created yet)

But with little modification to your answers I fixed the issue.

```
validate :one_answer_right

def one_answer_right
  count = 0
  answers.each do |a|
    if a.is_correct?
      count += 1
    end
  end
  errors[:base] << (count == 0 ? "One answer should be correct" : "Only one answer can be correct") unless count == 1
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your error message more meaningful with:

```
count = answers.count { |a| a.is_correct? }
errors[:base] << (count == 0 ? "One answer should be correct" : "Only one answer can be correct") unless count == 1
```

Comment: `answers.count` is giving me 0, whereas `answers.size` giving me 2

Comment: I was assuming answers were already retrieved. yes, count sends a count query to the database. You can do `answers.all.count { |a| a.is_correct? }` which accepts a block. If you do `answers.count`, you can pass in a conditions hash like `answers.count(:conditions => "is_correct = 1")` but this will send a query to the db.

Comment: answers can't be retrieved because the question and answer both gets submitted from single form. Just while submitting I've to check for the conditions. I fixed the issue. Thanks for the help. :)